# Batch - How to perform mathematical operations on time codes?

Tags: batch-file, awk, sed, cygwin, gnu

I've been working on a batch script, to change some `.xml` files format/type.

It's almost done, but I'm facing a problem changing the time codes.

Here is an example

```
  <Events>
    <Event In="00:00:20.650" Out="00:00:22.970"
    <Event In="00:00:23.050" Out="00:00:26.300"
```

This Time Format `hh:mm:ss.ms` should be changed to `hh:mm:ss:ff`

which means, changing the `Milliseconds` to `Frames`.

The Formula for doing so goes like this: `ms*25/1000` or for simplicity `ms*0.025`

Output should be

```
  <Events>
    <Event In="00:00:20:16" Out="00:00:22:24"
    <Event In="00:00:23:01" Out="00:00:26:08"
```

**Notes**

- 0.025 is the number of frames per Milliseconds.
- The number of frames MUST be an integer w/o any fractional component.
- I'm Using `GNUWin` and `Cygwin` library Tools, so it's okay to use `bc` `expr` , `tr` , `awk` `sed` or whatever solution to get the job done.

Comment: With pure [tag:batch-file] scripts, you can only do integer arithmetics using `set /A`, so you could split off the fractional seconds (ms) and do the `*25/1000` (losing the fractional part); however, since your sample data look like XML fragments, I suggest to use a language/command that natively supports XML format...

Comment: Math with numbers other than signed 32-bit integers is one of only two times I will ever recommend PowerShell over batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with an awk script:

**script.awk**

```
{ 
  re = "[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.([0-9]{3})"
  while( match( $0, re, grps) ) {
    frames = sprintf("%02.0f",( grps[1] *0.025 ) )
    gsub( "." grps[1], ":" frames)
  }
  print
}
```

Run it like this `awk -f script.awk yourfile`.

It tries to match such a timestamp and captures the last part (the milliseconds) into `grps[1]`. Then the calculation is done and `sprintf` is used to format the frames.

After that `gsub` replaces the milliseconds with the frames.

Comment: Many thanks Bro, That's exactly what I'm looking for :)
But, there is one problem. your script worked perfectly until the time code changed to 1 hour :( for example `01:00:04.309` and didn't work for the rest of the file. is it possible to modify the `script.awk` to fix that problem? Best Regards :)

Comment: I tried to modify your script by changing: `re = "[0.9]{2}`  to  `re = "[0-9]{2}` and it's perfectly working now. Thanks a lot bro, I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @rojo I was just waiting for him to modify his script .

Comment: @KorkOoO Oh.  I fixed it for him.  `:)`  Lars, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

**PowerShell:**

```js
[xml]$xml = gc events.xml

function fix([timespan]$ts) {
    "{0}:{1:D2}" -f $ts.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss"),[int]($ts.Milliseconds * 0.025)
}

$xml.SelectNodes('//Event') | %{
    $_.In = fix $_.In
    $_.Out = fix $_.Out
}

$xml.Save("events_fixed.xml")
```

If you'd rather have it as a batch script, you can convert this to a Batch + PowerShell polyglot by inserting this at the top and saving it with a .bat extension:

```js
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

powershell "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
goto :EOF

: end Batch / begin PowerShell hybrid code #>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution. This script is secure against all characters that have special meanings to `cmd`. Basically, it searches the given input file for keywords or attribute names `In` and `Out`, followed by `=` and a time code enclosed in quotation marks `""`. If found, the milliseconds portion is split off, converted to frames and appended to the remaining time code, separated by `:`. There can be an arbitrary number of time codes per line, all of them are recognised and converted as long as their format is like given in your sample data and one of the given keywords is preceded.

The script supports rounding of the converted values -- see the remarks (`rem`) at variable definition `FORMULA` at the beginning of the file (look it up in the block with the remark `Define constants here:`).

This is the code:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set KEYWORDS="In","Out" & rem // (provide a list of attribute names)
set "PATTERN=[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]"
set /A PLENGTH=12 & rem // (char. length of resolved `PATTERN` string)
set "FORMULA=(MS*25+0)/1000" & rem /* (`+0` means to round frames down;
rem   use `+999` instead to round up, or `+500` to round to nearest) */
set /A PADDING=2 & rem // (number of digits of resulting frame value)

set "FILE=%~1"
if not defined FILE exit /B 1

for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N /R "^" "%FILE%"') do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"
    if defined LINE (
        for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%E in ("!LINE!") do (
            endlocal
            set "LINE=%%E"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
    ) else (
        endlocal
        set "LINE="
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    for %%P in (!KEYWORDS!) do (
        endlocal
        set "KEYWORD=%%~P"
        call :PROCESS LINE LINE KEYWORD
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    echo(!LINE!
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B


:PROCESS  rtn_string  ref_string  ref_key
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "COLL="
set "LINE=!%~2!"
set "KEYW=!%~3!"
:LOOP
if defined LINE (
    call :LEN LLENGTH LINE
    call :LEN KLENGTH KEYW
    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%T in ("!KEYW!") do (
        set "SEEK=!LINE:*%%T=!"
    )
    if defined SEEK (
        if not "!SEEK!"=="!LINE!" (
            call :LEN SLENGTH SEEK
            set /A TLENGTH=LLENGTH-^(SLENGTH+KLENGTH^)
            for /F "tokens=1,2" %%M in ("!TLENGTH! !KLENGTH!") do (
                set "DONE=  !LINE:~,%%M!"
                set "TEST=!LINE:~%%M,%%N!"
            )
            set "CHAR=!DONE:~-1!" & set "CHAR=!CHAR:    = !"
            set "DONE=!DONE:~1!"
            if "!TEST!"=="!KEYW!" (
                if "!CHAR!"==" " (
                    set "DONE=!DONE!!KEYW!"
                    set "TEST=!SEEK!"
                    set /A TLENGTH=PLENGTH+3
                    for /F %%N in ("!TLENGTH!") do (
                        set "TEST=!SEEK:~,%%N!" & set "SEEK=!SEEK:~%%N!"
                    )
                    echo(!TEST! | > nul findstr /R /C:^^^"^^^^^^^=\"!PATTERN!\"^^^ $^^^"
                    if not ErrorLevel 1 (
                        for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%S in ("!TEST:~1!") do (
                            set "HHMMSS=%%~S" & set "MS=%%~T"
                            set /A "FF=%FORMULA%"
                            set "FF=0000!FF!" & set "FF=!FF:~-%PADDING%!"
                        )
                        set "COLL=!COLL!!DONE!="!HHMMSS!:!FF!"" & set "LINE=!SEEK!"
                    ) else (
                        set "COLL=!COLL!!DONE!!TEST!" & set "LINE=!SEEK!"
                    )
                ) else (
                    set "COLL=!COLL!!DONE!!TEST!" & set "LINE=!SEEK!"
                )
            ) else (
                set "COLL=!COLL!!DONE!!TEST!" & set "LINE=!SEEK!"
            )
        ) else (
            set "COLL=!COLL!!LINE!" & set "LINE="
        )
    ) else (
        set "COLL=!COLL!!LINE!" & set "LINE="
    )
    goto :LOOP
)
if defined COLL (
    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%E in ("!COLL!") do (
        endlocal
        set "%~1=%%E"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
) else (
    endlocal
    set "%~1="
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
)
endlocal
exit /B


:LEN  rtn_length  ref_string
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "STR=!%~2!"
if not defined STR (set /A LEN=0) else (set /A LEN=1)
for %%L in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if defined STR (
        set "INT=!STR:~%%L!"
        if not "!INT!"=="" set /A LEN+=%%L & set "STR=!INT!"
    )
)
endlocal & set "%~1=%LEN%"
exit /B
```

Supposing the script is saved as `convert-ms-to-frames.bat`, the input file is called `sample.xml` and the output file is called `return.xml`, use the following command line:

```
convert-ms-to-frames.bat "sample.xml" > "return.xml"
```

Simply remove the `> "return.xml"` part to display the output data on the console for testing.

---

Supposing the input file `sample.xml` contains the following data...:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
>   <Events>
>     <Event In="00:00:20.650" Out="00:00:22.970" />
>     <Event In="00:00:23.050" Out="00:00:26.300" />
>   </Events>
> ```

...the output file `return.xml` will contain the data below:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
>   <Events>
>     <Event In="00:00:20:16" Out="00:00:22:24" />
>     <Event In="00:00:23:01" Out="00:00:26:07" />
>   </Events>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Using bc

```
$ ms="650"
$ ff=$(echo ${ms} "*0.025/1" |bc)
$ echo $ff
16
```

I leave to you when the result is less then 10 to add the additonal "0"